# PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled in laravel 6 version

Tags: laravel-6

When I am trying To installing redis  in larvel  6 version I can not install redis and it extension it show me the error.[image]

Answer (score 11):

By default In Laravel 6 'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'), is not working but when i change this 'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis') .

Answer (score 6):

For ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-redis //7.2 is php version
```

then

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution in my case was:

- download Redis PHP extension (I used version https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.2.2/windows but you download a version for your php version from here https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/ )
- copy php_redis.dll in your ext folder (in my cas was laragon4\bin\php\php-7.4.0-nts-Win32-vc15-x64\ext)
- add to your php.ini extension=redis
- restart apache

My problem was that I had installed and working Redis but I hadn't the php extension.